# Images appearing locally but not when hosted

Tags: html, angular, src

I have a menu component html (src/menu/menucomponent) that exhibits images from a folder (src/assets/images/image.png) for the main nav when being viewed on a computer. Then I have a sidenav that is shown when on a mobile device.

The code is :

```
    <div id='main'>
<span class="hamburger" *ngIf="isMobile" (click)="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
<a  href=".#/welcome"*ngIf="!isMobile"class='menu'><img src ="../assets/images/Home.png"></a>
<a  href=".#/aboutme"*ngIf="!isMobile"class='menu'><img src ="../assets/images/About.png"></a>
<a href=".#/projects"*ngIf="!isMobile"class='menu'><img src ="../assets/images/Projects.png"></a>
<a  href=".#/contactme"*ngIf="!isMobile"class='menu'><img src ="../assets/images/Contact.png"></a>
<a  href=".#/subscribes"*ngIf="!isMobile"class='menu'><img src ="../assets/images/Subscribe.png"></a>
```

These images appear both locally and globally. Then I have the following:

```
   <div id='mySidenav' class='sidenav'*ngIf="isMobile">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" (click)="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href=".#/welcome" >Home</a>
  <a href=".#/aboutme" >About Me</a>
  <a href=".#/projects" >Projects</a>
  <a href=".#/contactme" >Contact</a>
  <a href=".#/subscribes">Subscribe</a>
    <a href='link1' class="tag"><img src="../assets/images/Image1.png"></a>
  <a href='link2' class="tag"> <img src="../assets/images/Image2.png"></a>
<a href='link3' class="tag"> <img src="../assets/images/Image3.png"></a>
 <a href='link4' class="tag"><img src="../assets/images/Image4.png" ></a>
```

These images appear locally but once hosted on a server, do not show, but the links still work. I have double-checked that they are in the same images folder and that they are the right image names.

Does anyone have some ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `assets` folder is copied to the `dist` when you compile the app.

So, you change your sources to:

```
<img src="./assets/images/Image1.png">
```

The `ng serve` can still figure out where the files are when you are testing locally.

Comment: Thanks for having a look into it. Unfortunately, it is still not working.

Comment: There has to be a linking issue as there is an error saying : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()

Comment: yes it does. I deleted the images and reuploaded them and still have the same error. Very bizarre because all other images in the images folder appear throughout my application except these 4.

Comment: Do you have other images in the `./assets/images` folder which appear without a problem after the proposed changes?

Comment: yeah, all other images work with the proposed changes

Comment: Make sure the image names are case matched. If all the other images, but this 4, can be seen, either they are not int the server or the names do not match. Howwver its also a bit of a puzzle that the server issue 403 (forbidden) rather than 404 (not found)

Comment: solution was using different images. Thanks for your help!